# Dll and assembly

Tags: assembly, dll

Is it possible to create a dll and change the asm code of an .exe at a specific location inside the dll?

Simple principle what I'm trying to achieve goes as following:

> Original code @00968808
> push eax
> push ebx

> Modified code @00968808 specified in dll
> push ecx
> push eax

P.S. I know I can do all of this just by editing the .exe with a debugger, but I want to do it through a dll if possible.

Comment: I'm confused. What code do you want to change and how? You talked about a DLL but then also about an EXE? DLLs entry-points (`DllMain` is their canonical name) are executed when loaded, there you can find the address of the code to change and use `VirtualProtect` and ordinary stores to edit it.

Comment: I want to modify asm code stored @00968808 through the dll. So when the dll gets loaded at the start of the program it modifies the .exe at that exact location with the code that I specified in the dll.